A equality between monotone class and $\lambda$ class with some certain conditions
It's an exercise in some books about measure theory.
Assume $C$ is a subset of $2^{\Omega}$. And we have the following two conditions:
1: If $A \in C$, then $A^c \in m(C)$, where $m(C)$ means the smallest monotone class containing $C$.
2: If $A,B \in C$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $A\cup B\in m(C)$.
Now we need to show that $\lambda(C) = m(C)$.
It is easy to know that $ m(C) \subset \lambda(C) $.
Set
$$D= \left\{ A\in m(C): \forall B \in C, if A\cap B = \varnothing ,then A\cup B\in m(C) \right\}$$
We want to show that such $D$ is a monotone class.
But how to prove the limit of decreasing sequence is still in $D$?
